# Using alpine source, why am I not able to source or "." my env file?

Tags: linux, docker

If I peek inside the image and ls in my directory, I see:

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Dec 10 22:30 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Dec 10 22:35 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           741 Dec  9 02:45 .env
```

I'm trying to `CMD source .env && ./myapp` (myapp is a placeholder, I have a lot more files in here!) but for some reason I get an issue - `.env file not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  Below works for me, but this also works - `CMD . ./.env && ./myapp`

Not sure why I can run `cat .env`, but I can't run `source .env`..

Comment: `CMD set -x; ls -l .env; . .env && ./myapp` might be a useful place to go -- if `ls -l` tells you the file doesn't exist, then you know that the directory your code is executing in is not the directory that you listed in the question. If, by contrast, `ls` says it *does* exist, then the `set -x` will mean that the commands *inside* the `.env` file get logged, so you can see which one is problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [exec form of `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "source .env && ./myapp" ]
```

That way, with the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the sourcing and not docker.

Make sure **[`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)** is set to the right folder first.

Comment: `source` is not guaranteed to work with `/bin/sh`. Use `.` instead, as described in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/dot.html.

Comment: That said, the shell form of `CMD` is very explicit in the docs that it runs with `/bin/sh`, and so should have identical behavior to the `exec` form in the use case at hand.

Comment: so this is weird, this worked - `CMD . ./.env && ./myapp`, but yours works too! :D